# Excel: Count if contains "="

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I've got a column that consists of about a thousand of "+","-" and "=" signs. I need to check which symbol appears the most times as a part of a bigger formula, but excel doesn't seem to count the "=" signs correctly. 
The following formula returns count of blank fields instead:

```
=COUNTIF(H3:H1005,"=")
```

While the 2 below work perfectly fine:

```
=COUNTIF(H3:H1005,"+")
=COUNTIF(H3:H1005,"-")
```

Is there anything I can do to make the formula work?

For the record I cannot change the the column in question and I would prefer to do this without creating a translation column if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
=COUNTIF(H3:H1005,"==")
```

Comment: Thank you, although the answer seems simple it would take me a while to figure this out.